# Display 3 Maximum values of a Column, include duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to display Highest 3 marks on a page, I am using following code.

```
Select * from myTable Marks Desc Limit 3.
```

It will works fine when there is no duplicate records.

My table

```
Name     Mark
------------
S1       90
S2       55
S3       60
S4       90
S5       55
S6       60
S7       88   
S8       45  
S9       88
```

Like aforesaid table, I want to show 3 records include duplicate records

So my final output looks like

```
Name     Marks
----------------
S1       90
S4       90
S7       88 
S9       88
S3       60
S6       60
```

Kindly please help me.

Comment: use distinct in your code, avoids duplicate data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First select the unique 3 best marks, then find all the records which have one of those marks:

```
SELECT name, mark 
FROM mytable AS t1 
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT(mark) AS best_marks FROM mytable ORDER BY mark DESC LIMIT 3) AS t2
    ON t1.mark = t2.best_marks
ORDER BY mark DESC, name ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try having a temporary table to store the top 3 records and display your result by joining to that table. 
Other than that, getting this in the same query would be complex and huge perfomance impact would be there.

Still if you insist, you can try this

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE mark IN (SELECT MAX(mark) FROM myTable) 
OR mark IN (SELECT MAX(mark) FROM myTable WHERE mark < (SELECT MAX(mark) FROM myTable)) 
OR mark IN (SELECT MAX(mark) FROM myTable WHERE mark < (SELECT MAX(mark) FROM myTable WHERE mark < (SELECT MAX(mark) FROM myTable)));
```

This will work only for top 3. If you want more, then you need to increase the or conditions in the where clause. But again, not good for performance

Comment: I don't want to be rude mate, but that query is ugly :) There's no need for such an headache, really. See my answer, it's actually easy. Cheers.

Comment: :) you are right. I was under the impression that limit does not work woth inner queries with join as it does not with union. Thanks for clearing that confusion... I tried yours and it works... Great!!

Comment: You're welcome :) It should be also not bad performance-wise: the subquery gets executed once, and then joined with the table. If `mark` is indexed, then it should be very fast also with a lot of data.